# Check if string matches url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, url

I've got a string url e.g. `"http://localhost:3839/MyController/Statement1/myResult"`

I need to do some logic on this i.e. if the url contains MyController/ and /myResult I need to redirect somewhere else.

Whats the easiest way to do this? I'm trying with regex but not sure how to do this.

Comment: You mean like [routing](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/asp-net-mvc-routing-overview-cs)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like below

```
string strURL=@"http://localhost:3839/MyController/Statement1/myResult";
if(strURL.contains("MyController") || strURL.contains("myResult")
{
  //redirect logic here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a new `Uri` instance, which will do the parsing for you. You can create an `Uri` instance for you URL as follows:

```
var uri = new Uri("http://localhost:3839/MyController/Statement1/myResult");
```

You can then use the properties of the `Uri` instance to extract the different parts of the URI:

```
Console.WriteLine(uri.AbsolutePath); // outputs "/MyController/Statement1/myResult"
Console.WriteLine(uri.Scheme);       // outputs "http"    
Console.WriteLine(uri.Host);         // outputs "localhost"    
Console.WriteLine(uri.Port);         // outputs "3839"
```